Getting a local cache with a huge delay
I am trying to force firebase to use data from the cache if the Internet connection is lost when working with my android application on React Native.
The idea is that when the user opens the screen, he sees a list of groups. The groups are stored in Firestore.
If there is an Internet connection, then there are no problems. However, if I turn off the Internet on the emulator, then working with the cache becomes absolutely strange.
What I'm doing and what I see::

I turn off the internet
Go to another application screen.
I return to the screen with the groups. I expect to see groups instantly downloaded from the cache.Instead, I wait 10 seconds before the groups appear.
I repeat steps 2-3, but this time it takes about a minute to wait.
I repeat steps 2-3 again, but this time it takes about a 8 mins to wait.
After another repetition, I was waiting about 5 mins.

All this time I have not turned on the Internet on the emulator. So the list of groups has returned from the cache. But why is it taking so long?
Please note that I specifically set the use of the cache in .get({source: 'cache'}).
Component Code:
  const fetchGroups = async () => {
    const grps = await firebaseConnector.getGroups();
    try {
      Alert.alert(`${grps.length}`);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('error');
    }
    setGroups([...grps]);
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      fetchGroups();
    }, []),
  );

FirebaseConnector method:
  async getGroups(): Promise<GroupItem[]> {
    try {
      var groupsItems: GroupItem[] = [];
      const grpsPartSnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection('GroupParticipants')
        .where('UserId', '==', this.userId)
        .get({source: 'cache'});

      const grpsIds = grpsPartSnapshot.docs.map(x => x.data().GroupId);
      for (const grpIndex in grpsIds) {
        var grpId = grpsIds[grpIndex];
        var grpInfo = await firestore()
          .collection('Groups')
          .doc(grpId)
          .get({source: 'cache'});

        groupsItems.push({
          id: grpInfo.id,
          name: grpInfo.data()?.Name,
          imageSource: grpInfo.data()?.Image,
        });
      }
      return groupsItems;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return [];
    }
  }

UPD
I noticed that the behavior changes depending on WHICH screen I go from. If I go from a blank screen, the groups appear as expected, instantly from the cache.
If I go from the screenshot where other information from the Firestore is rendered (for some reason always without problems), then I observe the behavior above.
UPD2
I have prepared a couple of animations to make it clearer...
with internet connection>>>
https://imgur.com/mxsAZcp
without internet connection>>>
https://imgur.com/gP8O19L

UPD3 I rebooted the laptop, rebuilt the application and it worked with the cache...but now it doesnt work again wtf((

I think I've realized my mistake.
The problem was that some methods were called with .get({source: 'server'}); first, even when there was no connection.
And after that, the method with .get({source: 'cache'}) was called;
